# WPF XAML Binding Not Picking Up DependencyProperty Value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a *really* simple `UserControl`

```
<UserControl x:Class="Namespace.Views.TabViews.TabViewTemplate"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="900" d:DesignWidth="880" 
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Type=TabViewTemplate}">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Grid Background="White">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="#FFB31B16" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="20" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="20" LineHeight="24" Margin="0,0,0,5" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Title}"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="1" Padding="20">
                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

and it's code behind

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace Namespace.Views.TabViews {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TabViewTemplate.xaml
    /// </summary>
    [ContentProperty("Content")]
    public partial class TabViewTemplate {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(TabViewTemplate), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    "Sample",
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                    OnTitleChanged)
                );

        private static void OnTitleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            var control = d as TabViewTemplate;
            if (control != null) control.Title = (string)e.NewValue;
        }

        public TabViewTemplate() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static void SetTitle(TabViewTemplate element, string value) {
            element.SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
        }

        public static string GetTitle(TabViewTemplate element) {
            return (string) element.GetValue(TitleProperty);
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

I make use of that code like this

```
<UserControl x:Class="Namespace.Views.TabViews.WelcomeTabView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
             xmlns:tabViews="clr-namespace:Namespace.Views.TabViews"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <tabViews:TabViewTemplate Title="Welcome">
        <Grid>
            <Border BorderBrush="Coral" BorderThickness="2" Margin="0">
                <Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="../../Resources/js_cfg_install_howto.gif"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </tabViews:TabViewTemplate>
</UserControl>
```

However the value "Welcome" gets `set` via the property -- I see this via a breakpoint on the property setter -- however the `get` is never called. I have used all sorts of Binding combinations, none of which work. What is the "correct" way to set the TextBlock Text by way of a `DependencyProperty`? Thanks!

Comment: Is `OnTitleChanged` being called? Try adding `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to the `Title` binding on the `TextBlock`. That'll give you a trace in the Output pane of how the Binding tries to resolve the source and the path, which ought to tell you where the trouble is.

Comment: The setter of a dependency property might not be called when its value is set in XAML. The reason is explained in the [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN. So putting a breakpoint there might be of no help.

Comment: That said, the structure of your UserControl looks dubious. Usually you just add elements to a top-level Panel in its XAML, and bind element properties (like TextBlock.Text) to dependency properties of the UserControl (like your Title property) by `Text={Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`.

Comment: Moreover, the statement `control.Title = (string)e.NewValue;` in your OnTitleChanged method doesn't make sense, because the value of the control's Title property is already the new value passed to the callback. It's redundant and useless to set it again.

Comment: FWIW, your binding and your dependency property work correctly for me. The XAML editor prefers `{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}` for the binding (yours gets a blue null-reference squiggle at design time), but both versions of the binding produce the same result at runtime.

Comment: Hang on: Are you seeing the correct results in the UI? Is the non-calling of the getter the only issue here? It's not going to call the getter when a Binding grabs the value, because it's a dependency property, so it'll go straight to `GetValue(TabViewTemplate.TitleProperty)`. The getter/setter property is just an optional courtesy thing for codebehind; the XAML would interact with the dependency property identically if you deleted the get/set thing. Attached properties work just fine that way.

Comment: It's also unclear why you have static `SetTitle` and `GetTitle` methods for a regular dependency property that is not an attached property. These methods are useless.

Answer (score 1):

It was working. My TextBlock needed a Foreground of Black in order to see the text.

Comment: You could have deleted the question.